# Why Amex card not being validated in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

When I enter amex 15 digit card on chrome input field for credit cards, chrome gives validation error as "Please match the requested format". My card in fine and no. are right too. I think bug is on chrome for amex specific case. How can I resolve this issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Justo put 'novalidate' property on Form tag, chrome validator for the form will be disabled and solved. Thanks.